# Custom functions in excel is working for excel desktop but not working on excel web

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I am testing Custom functions in excel add-in deployed (after npm run build) on Azure static web. I am able to open sideload in excel desktop application but whenever I try to load ***same manifest file*** in excel web (Build 16.0.14430.31875), add-in loaded successfully but I am not able to use function.
[My Git hub repo is saved here.](https://github.com/techindia2010/test-function)

manifest.xml is updated based on web server.

What is the possible solution.?

snapshot of files loaded.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udYQy.png)

snapshot of error in console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np7Mp.png)

snapshot of network flow.   Just to update, i am using Edge browser, managed by IT admin. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7p4d.png)

[Snapshot of loaded files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mxt7.png) after addition of `<script src="functions.js"></script>` in taskpane.

Comment: What is the possible solution?

Comment: @SolarMike, I am trying to get possible solution.

Comment: Did you notice any errors in excel web with F12 develop tool?

Comment: @xiaochun, I have added snapshot of  loaded files and snapshot of error in console have been added. Please note that function.js is not loaded. taskpane.js is loaded after i click on load taskpane.

Comment: @ShaileshPatel, thanks to share the snapshots. The root cause that custom function cannot be used is due to the functions.js file is not loaded. May you please check the network flow to see if there is any error happened when loading functions.js?

Comment: @xiaochun, I have added snapshot of network flow too. while loading add-in, funciton.js is not getting loaded in web. but same manifest works fine in desktop.

Comment: @xiaochun, manifest.xml is also saved in GitHub repo.

Comment: @ShaileshPatel could you please add following code snippet in taskpane.html? 
<script src="functions.js"></script>,
which is to load the "functions.js" file explicitly when opening the taskpane.

Comment: @xiaochun-Microsoft, I have added <script src="functions.js"></script> in  taskpane.html, function.js is loaded but no luck with visibility of function.  Snapshot of loaded file have been added in main post.

Comment: @ShaileshPatel sorry to hear that it does not work. May you please check if there is "functions.json" file loaded? And is functions.json file accessible? 

I tried with your sample and it worked at my side by adding "functions.js" in taskpane.html file explicitly. BTW, is your repo updated with the latest change? I can take a further look then.